# Finding approximation of root

Tags: numerical-methods

AS for newton approximation of the reciprocal of the square root of 5. Does the function f(x)=1/x - 5^1/2 apply for newton method

Answer (score 1):

No, because if you know $5^{1/2}$ to use in $f(x)$, then clearly you know 
$\dfrac{1}{5^{1/2}}$.

The usual Newton's method for finding the reciprocal of the square root of $a$ uses $f(x)=\dfrac{1}{x^2}-a$, which has the advantage that the Newton iteration does not need a division:
$$
x_{n+1} = \frac{x_{n}(3-ax_n^2)}{2}
$$